# Is $x=0$ a saddle point of the potential $V(x)=\frac{k}{4}x^4$?

Tags: calculus, classical-mechanics, maxima-minima

I'm a physics student. I came across a potential $V(x)$ of the form $$V(x)=\frac{k}{4}x^4$$ with $k>0$. For this potential $V^\prime(0)=0$ and  also$V^{\prime\prime}(0)=0$ implies that the point $x=0$ is neither a maximum nor a minimum but a *saddle point*. But intuitively, if we plot the function $V(x)$, there is a plateau around $x=0$ which strongly suggests that it is a minimum and doesn't quite look like a [saddle point](https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/maxima-minima.html).

Does my intuition fail or is $x=0$ really a saddle point?

Comment: It is a minimum. $V''(x)=0$ does not imply it's neither a max nor min.

Comment: Doesn't $V^{\prime\prime}(x_0)=0$ imply that $x=x_0$ a saddle point? I have put a link. Isn't it the definition of a saddle point?

Comment: is the Parameter $k$ positive?

Comment: Yes. I've mentioned that $k>0$.

Comment: As I just said, no (assuming the definition of a saddle pt is that it has first derivative zero but is not a max or min). If it has first derivative zero and nonzero second it is a maximum or minimum, but having first and second derivative zero does not imply it is not a max/min, as this example shows. It could be a max min or saddle. If the third derivative is nonzero it must be a saddle.

Comment: If the definition of saddle point is that the first and second derivative are zero (a bad definition considering the visual suggestion of the name in my opinion, and also not the definition on Wikipedia) then local max/min and saddle are not mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $V$ in fact attains a global minimum at $x=0$. To see this, consider that $V(x)=\frac{k}{4} x^4\ge 0$ because $x^4=(x^2)^2\ge 0$ and $\frac{k}{4}>0$. Further, elementary algebra shows that $x^4=0$ has only one solution: namely $x=0$.

The second derivative test is inconclusive in the case that $f''(x_0)=0$. Such a point $x_0$ could be a minimum point, a maximum point, or neither – i.e. a saddle point.

Comment: I think the name saddle point is used for at least two variable functions. For one variable functions, one has points of inflection where not only the second derivative vanishes but also changes sign across that point.

Comment: That's true. In essence it is the same phenomenon though.

Answer (score 1):

since we have $$V^{(iv)}(x)=6k>0$$ and the order of the derivative is even we have there a Minimum
see about Theorem of higher derivatives